# Restart/undo conflict resolution in a single file

Tags: git, git-merge

In a larger git merge with several conflicting files, I incorrectly marked a file as resolved (using `git add FILE` after some editing)

Now I'd like to undo my conflict resolution attempt and start over resolving that file.

How can I do that?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373812/rollback-file-to-much-earlier-version

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Use `git checkout` with [flag `--merge` (short version `-m`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt--m):

```
git checkout --merge FILE
```

This restores the unresolved state, including all information about parent and merge base, which allows restarting the resolution.

This command can also be used to "undo" automatic merge conflict resolution, if [`rerere` is enabled](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) in your git config. This is especially useful with [enabled `rerere.autoUpdate`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rerereautoUpdate) after it records incorrect merge conflict resolution and you notice too late.

Found the solution here: http://gitster.livejournal.com/43665.html

Comment: +1; this is the actual solution :) `git reset` won’t touch the file.

Comment: This really helped me out since it put the file back into it's pre-conflict resolution state. What's interesting is that instead of the two merge points being named "head" and {REVISION}, they're now called "ours" and "theirs".

Comment: Worked perfectly after I accepted the version from the wrong side.

Comment: "file is still marked with `both modified`". That's exactly the intended result of the question.

Comment: `-m` as in `--merge`

Comment: As of more modern versions of git, the updated solution would be: `git restore -m FILE`.

Comment: This does not work if the resolution of a conflict was to delete the file. Neither `checkout` nor `restore` works.