# force git mergetool to amend a previously done merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I use `DiffMerge` for 3-way merges in `git`.  I just completed a mandatory merge job but realized I missed something out and would like to remerge and use the same 3-way GUI functionality.  When I tried:

```
git mergetool my/path/file.ext
```

I got

```
No files need merging
```

How can I force `mergetool` to be able to do a 3-way merge in a GUI again rather than saving the remote under a different name and fishing out for deltas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and reset the file to its pre-merged state, as mentioned in "[Git merging: Restart conflict resolution in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409744/6309)":

```
git checkout -m -- your/File
```

And then relaunch `git mergetool`.

That supposes you didn't completed the merge and made a commit.

Comment: `git checkout -m -- your/File` didn't really "reset the file to its pre-merged state"

Comment: @amphibient were you able to redo the merge though?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for conflicts upon `stash pop`.