# What commands is required to revert changes made by git mergetool?

Tags: git, git-merge, revert, mergetool

I have made some changes to a number of conflicting files as the result of a a `git pull` command,  using the `git mergetool` command, but I want to revert it back to the state before I made the changes with the mergetool.

It is basically the state where git warns that there are conflicts and lists them. What command is required for that?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409420/restart-undo-conflict-resolution-in-a-single-file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is actually a way to "simulate" a merge and view its conflicts. However, you can certainly run the merge, view the conflicts, and immediately undo it using:

```
git reset --merge
```

For v1.7.4 and later, you can also use:

```
git merge --abort
```