# How to merge again a already merged but not commited file without restarting the whole merge

Tags: git, merge

While merging I got conflicts from 7 different files. 
I merge them one by one with using "git mergetool" .

Now I realized that I made a mistake while merging one of this files. 
Instead of reseting to base or using "git merge reset" which will cost me redo all my merging work, Can I just restart the merge on the specific conflicted file?

Comment: `git checkout -m FILE` ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409420/restart-conflict-resolution-in-a-single-file))