# Git merge revert file to conflict mode

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

1. I run `git merge`
2. the Auto merge fails and I get conflict
3. I change the file (to solve the conflict)

how to revert to 2 **on a specific file** without loss the other changed I make

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restart/undo conflict resolution in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409420/restart-undo-conflict-resolution-in-a-single-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file into the original conflicted content after merge?

```
git checkout -m -- path-to-file
```

Don't know if `git restore` can do it as well.