# Ruby on rails, change code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

I built a ruby on rails application, with my friend, but then had to delete my code because I made a giant mistake, I downloaded the code from my friend but the application did not work. Would I have redo all of my routes in terminal. If so, is it possible with all of my code being complete, and not doing it step by step?

Comment: You'll have to redo everything you did that your friend didn't have in their code. You'll also have to learn about revision control so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: If I pushed my code to GITHUB, but my last 2 pushes were bad, is there anyway that I could download an earlier version of my code?

Comment: A bit of googling for "git rollback" might be useful, that will find you things like http://stackoverflow.com/q/373812/479863

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either check your `git log` for the SHA you're interested in, and `git checkout <SHA>`, or you could do a `git reset --soft HEAD^^` if you want to preserve those changes on staging (assuming you only need to go back two commits as the ^ correspond to how many commits you need to go back).

Comment: Also, if you need to go back several commits, you could use `git reset --soft HEAD~40` to go back 40 commits.  This just saves you from holding down the `^`.  Cheers!